# Add click events on autogenerated by overflow handler menu items

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Say, I have a container with `{ layout: {type: "hbox", overflowHandler: {handler: {type: "Menu"}}}`

Then I'm beginning to add buttons with `btn.on("click", ...` handlers.
Surprisingly, those click handlers won't be delegated automatically to menu items, which is created with `Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Menu`.

I've tried to listen to containers "add" event - in order to catch all the component added and, if needed, to provide additional event handlers, but menu button, created with Menu object, just not captured with containers add event.

So my question is  - what is best way to sync click events between buttons and menu items, which, actually, have one-to-one correspondence with buttons.

Comment: Have you tryied a Controller? Even if you no using the MVC pattern, a controller will make that really easy for you...

Comment: @VoidMain, what do you actually mean?

Comment: I'll give you an example later.